# Замена template для верхнего state в angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Разбираюсь с существующей системой, написанной на Redux + Angular1.5, ES6.

**Дано:**

```
$stateProvider
.state('app.section', {
    ...
    template: '<section-header></section-header>'
    redirectTo: 'app.section.levelOne'
    ...
})
.state('app.section.levelOne', {
    ...
    template: '<section-levelOne></section-levelOne>'
    ...
})
.state('app.section.levelOne.first', {
    ...
    template: '<section-levelOne-first></section-levelOne-first>'
    ...
})
.state('app.section.levelOne.second', {
    ...
    template: '<section-levelOne-second></section-levelOne-second>'
    ...
});
```

**Описание и задача:**

Когда мы зашли в нужный раздел приложения (*app.section*), у нас загрузился шаблон (*section-header*), следом догрузился еще шаблон первого уровня вложенности раздела (*levelOne*) - получили заголовок раздела со своим контроллером и основную информацию раздела со своим.

В первом уровне вложенности мы можем перейти еще на один уровень вниз (например, first) - в этот момент необходимо изменить шаблон section-header, в частности поменять информацию в некоторых местах и подключить новые контролы.

Как это можно сделать? у меня других идей, кроме как переносить всё из section-header в "нижние" шаблоны, нет.

Кто поможет, кто подскажет?

Comment: на самом деле все очень просто и зависит от того, во что рендерится `section-header` - angular-ui-router поддерживает много вью в стейтах, и даже можно указать в каком из стейтов какой шаблон выводить

Comment: @Grundy действительно просто, оказалось надо использовать символ собаки для атрибута view, тогда можно в дочернем state подменить весь шаблон. Мне это подошло вполне

Comment: если вы сами нашли решение, можете опубликовать его :)